# PowerShell variable value is not retained

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm new with Powershell.

There is something that amazes me the way PS works, especially how it retains the variable.

Example:

```
[string]$a=""    
$a = "world" 
$b = "Hello $a" 
write-host $b 

$a = "world2" 
write-host $b
```

The following is what is resulted:

```
Hello world
Hello world
```

Why the second write-host does not display "Hello world2"?

Comment: Actually, this is how most languages work!

Answer (score 1):

Just because when you write `$b = "Hello $a"` the value of `$a` is expended and the new string is `Hello world`.

Answer (score 0):

Like said JPBlanc, you variable is rewrited...

You can do this :

```
$a = "world" 
Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable b -Mode Read -Action { $global:b = "Hello $a" }

write-host $b  

$a = "world2" 
write-host $b
```

Or simply use a function:

```
function SayHello($who){
"Hello $who"
}

$a = "world" 
SayHello($a)

$a = "world2" 
SayHello($a)
```

Comment: No, debugging entry point should be kept for debugging not for programming.

Comment: Of course I agree with you, but any method deserves to be known. If we start sorting according to this or that criteria, we do not learn anything ... No?